# Update progress using asp:update

Tags: html, asp.net

i need to show progress as a modal in my page.
i have written the following code but it is not working.
On clicking the submit button the modal is not getting displayed.
i have spent enough hours googling but no use.
Can anyone please help?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
        scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.Button1);
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.modal
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: Black;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity: 0.6;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
}
.center
{
    z-index: 1000;
    margin: 300px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 130px;
    background-color: White;
    border-radius: 10px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity: 1;
}
.center img
{
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div class="modal">
                <div class="center">
                    <img alt="" src="/Content/images/loading.gif" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div align="center">
                <h1>
                    Click the button to see the UpdateProgress!</h1>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script runat="server">

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
    scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(this.Button1);
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
</script>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="center">
                <img alt="" src="/Content/images/loading.gif" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div align="center">
            <h1>
                Click the button to see the UpdateProgress!</h1>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="click" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Update:** Try adding `AsyncPostBackTrigger`. I have updated the code above.

Comment: nope it did not work . i am getting error as Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.

Comment: Can you view in the networks window in the developer console window after the button has been clicked. Check if the postback is returning a http status code 500.

Comment: no as soon as i click the button i get the above error on the developer console window

Comment: have you tried commenting the `Thread.Sleep()` line? If yes and still that error is there. Try placing a break point and then debug application to find out exact line of error. I would have done it myself but I'm not getting that error.

Comment: **Update your code with AsyncPostBackTrigger** and then try. I have updated the code.

Comment: Upon Googling a bit. I got one more solution of your error `Parser Error Exception`. Try adding this in your **web.config** file.

_<appSettings>

  <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="100000" />

</appSettings>_

Comment: i have added that line in the web config file.still no use

Comment: i have found out that the function Button1_Click is not fired when the asp:button is clicked

Comment: Have you tried adding the `Triggers` as in the code above?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your UpdateProgress tag is outwith your update panel content template.  Put the UpdateProgress tag within your update panel content template and it'll work.

Also note, you don't need the code in your page load. Controls are registered by default.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div class="modal">
                    <div class="center">
                        <img alt="" src="/Content/images/loading.gif" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>

        <div align="center">
            <h1>
                Click the button to see the UpdateProgress!</h1>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```